# Windows Batch file printing block text to console

Tags: windows, batch-file, console, echo

I have a batch file that just executes some simple db scripts, and at the end of it i want to put block text from one of those text generators to display on the console of whoever is running it... Im not sure how to achieve this. Tried putting Echo in front of every line but this is not the correct approach.

please help?

I cant seem to paste my example text, it doesnt show nicely, but its the kindof
thing created [here](http://bigtext.org/)

Example file:

```
REM Move the folder location to where the sql scripts are saved locally:
cd D:\Development\Fusion\SQL\Database Clear
call sqlplus system/password as sysdba "@step1.sql" 
call sqlplus system/password as sysdba "@step2.sql"
REM Insert block text here
pause
```

Comment: simply `type block.txt`

Comment: Okay cool that does work thanks, but is it possible to embed the text within my file instead of referencing an external file like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can include your block text at the end of the bat file, prepend every line with a couple of spaces, and make sure your code does not have any line prepended by two spaces.

then you can use `findstr` to display only the lines in the bat file itself that begin with two spaces:

```
@echo off
REM Move the folder location to where the sql scripts are saved locally
pushd D:\Development\Fusion\SQL\Database Clear
call sqlplus system/password as sysdba "@step1.sql" 
call sqlplus system/password as sysdba "@step2.sql"
popd
REM show block text    
findstr /r /c:"^  " %~f0
goto :eof
   _____       ____  _      ___       _  ____ 
  |___ / _   _|  _ \| |__  / _ \ _ __(_)/ ___|
    |_ \| | | | |_) | '_ \| | | | '__| | |    
   ___) | |_| |  __/| | | | |_| | |  | | |___ 
  |____/ \__,_|_|   |_| |_|\___/|_|  |_|\____|
```